# How do i insert a new line after every dictionary key pair print using dictionary comprehension as done by the pprint function in Python?

Tags: python, printing, line, new-operator

from pprint import pprint
MyDict={"a":list(range(1,10)),"b":list(range(11,20)),"c":list(range(21,30))}
pprint((MyDict))

Comment: Please, i do not want to use the pretty-print function"pprint"

Comment: Please post the expected output.

Comment: #thanks, here is a sample output with pprint
{'a': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
'b': [11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19],
'c': [21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29]}

Comment: This is what I get when I ran your code. Add this to the question with the format you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
MyDict={"a":list(range(1,10)),"b":list(range(11,20)), "c":list(range(21,30))}

for key in MyDict:
    print(key, MyDict[key])
```

Comment: Thanks Nuno, this is exactly the output i want. However i will like to know how to achieve same with the '\n' in the print statement. Especially if i used the dictionary comprehension.

Answer (score 0):

```
for k,v in MyDict.items():
   print(k + ':' +' '+ v.__str__() +',')
```

Comment: Thanks a million, this is exactly what i am looking for. Though i will like to use the code in dictionary comprehension like this                                                                        print({k + ':' +' '+ v.__str__() +',' for k,v in MyDict.items() })

Answer (score 0):

```
print(*(' '.join(map(str, x)) for x in MyDict.items()), sep='\n')
```

Comment: Thanks Jordan, this produces the desired output. I am still trying to figure out the role of the wildcard(*). Can you please direct me to some online resource where i could read more on this? Thanks

Comment: The asterisk tells Python to pass all the values as arguments rather than passing the container as a single argument. E.g. `print(*(1, 2, 3))` is the same as `print(1, 2, 3)`. You can find more details in the Python documentation: https://docs.python.org/2.7/reference/expressions.html#calls